# Replicating Netflix for web effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to replicate an effect of the web version of Netflix. When you click on row-1 the box containing details for that row (details-row-1) appears, pushing down the row-2. If you click on row-1 again its details disappear and row-2 takes its original place. Problem is, when the details row appears I scroll down (to read its content) and when I click row-1 again and the details-row-1 is hidden the scroll jumps to the beginning of the page. In contrast, in Netflix when you close the details box for a movie the scroll doesn't move at all.

I've tried adding return false and prevent default to prevent the scrolling up but that didn't work.

This is what I have so far.

**HTML**

```
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="banner">banner</div>
  <div class="row-1">row 1
    <div class="details-row-1">details for row 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-2">row 2</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".row-1").click(function(e){
    $(".details-row-1").toggleClass('open');
    $(".row-2").toggleClass('open');
    return false;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.boxes {
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.boxes .banner {
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
.row-1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.row-1 .details-row-1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    top: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
}
.row-1 .details-row-1.open {
    opacity: 1;
}
.row-2 {
    border: 2px solid green;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.row-2.open {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,  200px,  0);
    transform: translate3d(0,  200px,  0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/znLbzbt9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser scrolls up because your page gets smaller after you remove the box. To keep your page in the same size avoiding scrolling you can set the height of boxes to 1600px.

Comment: Thanks! adding a height to "boxes" works. Any reason it should be 1600px specifically?

Comment: I added the height of 4 boxes together to get that number.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is a sure-fire way to fix this, without setting a fixed height to your page. The page isn't jumping back to the start like you are saying, rather it is removing the scroll bar because the page length has been decreased since that element is no longer showing.

One suggestion I do have, however, is to add an "invisible" box, at the bottom, that is the same height as your description. This may help mitigate how often the jump occurs due to window height.

It seems this will occur when the page does not begin with any scroll bar. You may be able to try some tricks with changing the `overflow` property.

Also, unless you are really aiming to do all animations with CSS3, I would suggest looking at jQuery's `slideToggle()` function.